# How to turn Flash Light On/Off using Mobile Vision API?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm using mobile vision to recognize text on images. This is pretty much my MainActivity:

```
package com.usama.textrecognitionbycamera;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // welcome ..
    SurfaceView cameraView;
    TextView textView;
    CameraSource cameraSource;

    final int RequestCameraPermission = 1001;


    // 3
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestCameraPermission: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cameraView = findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);


        // 1
        final TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
            Log.w("MainActivity", "Detected dependence are not found ");
        } else {
            cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                    .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                    .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                    .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .build();

            // 2
            cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    try {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    RequestCameraPermission);
                        }
                        cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    cameraSource.stop();
                }
            });


            // 4
            textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
                @Override
                public void release() {

                }

                @Override
                public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
                    final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
                    if (items.size() != 0 ){
                        textView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                for (int i = 0 ;i < items.size();i++){
                                    TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                                    stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                                }
                                textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                                Log.d("Text",stringBuilder.toString());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#CE3030"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="no text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I request camera permission in the manifest and here's the vision lib implementation:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'
```

Now, the documents doesn't say anything about using the flash light so I tried to improvise by using the camera manager from:

```
android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
```

I initialize the camera manager in onCreate:

```
mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
try {
    mCameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
} catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and switching the flash light on in the surfaceCreated callback of cameraView.getHolder() like so

```
try {
    mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, true);
} catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And, guess what, I turned on the flash light but now I'm unable to turn it off. I tried with setTorchMode(mCameraId, false) but no luck. I want it to toggle between on and off. I'm guessing I have two connections (CameraSource and CameraManager) to the camera source, so I'm able to turn it on but not off since  the vision mobile api is using it.

Any workaround here?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually an easy one. All it took was to stop the camera source and start it again. See code below for more details:

```
private void startTorch() {
        // torch, from cmera2, needs to start with scanner camera
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    RequestCameraPermission);
        }
        try {
            cameraSource.stop();
            mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, true);
            isTorchOn = true;
            cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            helper.showAlert(this, "Starting Camera Error", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            helper.showAlert(this, "Starting Camera Error", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private void stopTorch() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    RequestCameraPermission);
        }
        try {
            cameraSource.stop();
            mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, false);
            isTorchOn = false;
            cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            helper.showAlert(this, "Starting Camera Error", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            helper.showAlert(this, "Starting Camera Error", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```